# Devise will not let me register a user while logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, login-control

I'm using devise for the user system but I have one problem. I'd like for a logged-in user to register new user. It's a question of security. However, a logged-in user can not currently register a new user.

I dont know how fix this.

Thanks by help!

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the easist way would be just to turn off the devise config option **:registerable**, this will get rid of the sign_up paths and links.

Then just build your own user controller actions and views to interact directly with your User model.

The default devise registrations controller wants to auto create a new session for the newly created user which is why it won't let logged in users create another user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Devise [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface) explains how to do that kind of thing.

You don't need to over-ride anything in devise. Just treat it like any other namespaced resource.

Comment: Didn't find this answer and link useful at all.

Comment: From 5 years ago, but, uhh, looking back on this I don't even understand the question anymore.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Just needed to namespace the users for admin so it didn't conflict with Devise's routes.  Thanks @jamesconant

Comment: You are certainly welcome, @MarkEvans. Glad it helped!